# How do I take a screenshot of FSX using a C++ Program?

Tags: c++, screenshot, steam

I'm working on a program that works with the game "Microsoft Flight Simulator X: Steam Edition." One of the things I need to do with it is take a screenshot of the game. I've tried several different solutions to no avail. To take the screenshot I am trying to issue a F12 keypress to trigger Steam to take a screenshot. Here's a couple of examples of what I tried:

```
keybd_event(VK_F12, 0, 0, 0);
Sleep(250);
keybd_event(VK_F12, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

This second example confirmed that the keypress is being registered, but no screenshots are being taken.

```
INPUT input[1] = {};
input[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
input[0].ki.wVk = VK_F12;
UINT test = SendInput(ARRAYSIZE(input), input, sizeof(INPUT));
std::cout << test;
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to get this to work, or other ways to take a screenshot, please let me know!

Comment: Assuming you are on windows10, what about `win + PrtScr`.

Comment: Search the internet for "snipping tool".  If you have windows 10, you can enter that into the search box on the bar.

Comment: I need an automated way of screenshotting. One that I can call in a program because I will be doing the action hundreds of times.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the version maybe by this the problem is solved.